# Вопросы в пути до файлов в место русских букв

Tags: qt, url

Файл не открывается из-за вопросов вместо русских букв:

```
"D:/My Programs/build-ObservationLog-Desktop_Qt_5_11_0_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug/Журнал_0_Пн_июн_25_2018/Видеокамера/00887.MTS"
ShellExecute 'file:///D:/My Programs/build-ObservationLog-Desktop_Qt_5_11_0_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug/??????_0_??_???_25_2018/???????????/00887.MTS' failed (error 2).
```

Почему вдруг стали появляться вопросы в пути? Причём некоторые файлы открываются нормально.

hrefdelegate.cpp:

```
            QUrl url = QUrl::fromUserInput(index.model()->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toString());
            if(url.isValid())
              QDesktopServices::openUrl(url);
```

Пробовал и так :

```
    QTextCodec *codec_1251 = QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251");
    QString string = codec_1251->toUnicode(index.model()->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toByteArray());
    QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(string)));
```

Тут тоже ShellExecute failed (error 2):

```
ShellExecute 'file:///D:/My Programs/build-ObservationLog-Desktop_Qt_5_11_0_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug/Журнал_0_Вт_июн_26_2018/test/00882.MTS' failed (error 2).
```

Возможно дело в смене компилятора с mingw на MSVC2017_64bit/ Но это только предположение. Как изменить код чтоб работали ссылки?

Comment: Я помню что в qt4.8 он не мог сохранять нормально русские буквы, это код хоть и компилировался `QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251")` почему то не отрабатывал. НО в qt5.10 такой проблемы нет, посмотри пример кода в интернете есть примеры. Я думаю у тебя проблема с `QDesktopServices` но возможно это связанно стем фактом что я просто адреса складывал в вектор.

Comment: @timob256 Да скорей всего с QDesktopService, но вот проблему так и не понял как решить.

Comment: А как к вам попадает `index.model()->data`? Вполне возможно, там уже символы `?` вместо правильных букв и с этим ничего не сделать.

Comment: @mr NAE Как так ? Вообще это берётся из базы в кодировке UTF8(PostgreSQL), А потом заполнятся QAbstractItemModel *model в QTableView.

Comment: Через делегаты я получаю эту ссылку: bool HrefDelegate::editorEvent(QEvent *event,
                                   QAbstractItemModel *model,
                                   const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                   const QModelIndex &index) {
    if ((event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease) || (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick)) {
        if (index.row()!=0) {
            QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(string)));
        }
    }
}